# Position text in margin relative to paper border

Tags: latex, tex

I'm trying to write a macro that positions text in the margin of a LaTeX document. The text should appear in the same line the macro is called. Horizontal text position should be relative to the absolute border of the paper rather than the left side of the text.

I tried with the tabto package using the `\tabto*` command and then jump back to the location in the text with `\tabto*{\TabPrevPos}`. This works well but since `tabto` positions relative to the  border of the text the result is different if you are in a list environment or similar.
So the whole command looks similar to:

```
\newcommand{\sidenote}[1]{%
  \tabto*{\sidenoteskip}%
  \smash{%
    \begin{minipage}[t][1ex][t]{\sidenotewidth}%
      \textbf{#1}%
    \end{minipage}%
  }%
  \tabto*{\TabPrevPos}%
}
```

Does anywone have an idea how I can position the  minipage relative to left paper border and jump back to the location where the macro was called?

Comment: Why don't you use `\marginpar`?

Comment: `marginpar` can only be used in outer par mode and this often is not the case. But I found a working solution now here [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86049/position-margin-notes-relative-to-left-margin-in-plain-tex)